# How to override the hashcode method according to this special equals logic

Tags: java, spring, hashmap

We have a special logic for a "equals" method, like below:
We use idTypeA/idTypeB/idTypeC as key to compare, only if they are not empty for both objects. How to correctly override the hashCode method, accordingly this kind of equals logic ?

```
public class Student {
private String idTypeA;
private String idTypeB;
private String idTypeC;
public Student(String idTypeA, String idTypeB, String idTypeC) {
    this.idTypeA = idTypeA;
    this.idTypeB = idTypeB;
    this.idTypeC = idTypeC;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof Student)){
        return false;
    }
    Student keyIn = (Student) obj;

    if ((!idTypeA.isEmpty()) && (!keyIn.idTypeA.isEmpty())) {
        if (0 == idTypeA.compareToIgnoreCase(keyIn.idTypeA)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if ((!idTypeB.isEmpty()) && (!keyIn.idTypeB.isEmpty())) {
        if (0 == idTypeB.compareToIgnoreCase(keyIn.idTypeB)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if ((!idTypeC.isEmpty()) && (!keyIn.idTypeC.isEmpty())) {
        if (0 == idTypeC.compareToIgnoreCase(keyIn.idTypeC)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    // TODO ??? How to correctly override the hashCode method
    // according to above equals method
    return super.hashCode();
}
}
```

Thanks,

Frank

Comment: You know you can also use `equalsIgnoreCase()`, right?

Comment: Also, it's a strange `equals()` implementation. Normally you expect `equals()` to return true if both values are empty. Feels impossible to write a good `hashCode()` implementation for this scenario, but better minds will undoubtedly prove me wrong.

Comment: Why the default implementation of the hashCode() is not good for you? What is the constraint condition for it that you are trying to satisfy?

Comment: @Hack06 Relying on the default `hashCode()` implementation in this case would violate the `equals()`/`hashCode()` contract.

Comment: Probably returning 0 if one of the keys is empty, and a hash of the three keys otherwise, is about the best you can do. Inefficient if you have a lot of empty keys, but I don't think it can be helped.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yes, I know this is a little weird. But the businees requirement is like this. We can't predict which key has value in database. 
So we just use the one both not empty to do the comparison. This is the problem caused me puzzled on how to write the hashCode correctly.

Comment: In that case I stick with my suggestion from my previous comment. You could technically return a random `hashCode()` if one of the keys is empty, but that would probably be more inefficient than just returning 0 and deferring to `equals()`. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Isn't the equals method flawed? What if idTypeA and idTypeB are filled where A is the same and B isn't? also I would expect it to blow up, as `isEmpty` doesn't work with a `null` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `equals` method isn't transitive:

- `("a", "", "c")` is equal to `("a", "b", "c")`
- `("a", "b", "c")` is equal to `("", "b", "d")`
- But `("a", "", "c")` isn't equal to `("", "b", "d")`

This means that your equals method doesn't meet the requirements on overriding `equals()`.

It's fine to have application-specific notions of "equality" (a reasonably common one is "almost equal to"). But you just can't shoe-horn these into Java's specific notions of `equals()` (and `hashCode`) because code relying on the documented properties of equals (reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity etc) won't behave as expected.

As such, it doesn't really make sense to ask how to implement `hashCode()`, because it can't meet the requirements of that either.

Comment: I like your idea. I thought it over and also feel this should be my fault to have asked a misleading question. 

Our map to store the objects is not very big(thousands), but it will be searched for many many times(millions). So I will change the design. I will add a new UUID as key to the object. When a new object created, it will look through the map, use a function "IsTheSame"(not equals) to do the job. If it not exsit in the map, it will generate a new UUID for the key, otherwise use the same key. The equals and hashcode only refer to the UUID. 

Thanks for all your guys' great help!

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it you have two basic options:

1. Return `0` if one of the keys is empty, and a regular hash code based on the key values otherwise.
   This might be inefficient if you expect to have a lot of empty keys, as most lookups will have to defer to `equals()` to verify that a match has been found.
2. Return a random hash code if one of the keys is empty, and a regular hash code based on the key values otherwise.
   This is inefficient because generating random values is expensive in terms of processing, but lookups will be fast.

So it's a bit of a catch 22. Both approaches are valid and don't violate the `equals()`/`hashCode()` contract, but they come with different performance trade-offs.

Comment: I get your idea. The hashcode is just used to decide the object to put into which bucket of the map. The equals can be used to compare the objects in the same bucket. Even though they were put into different bucket,  actually equal objects, seems not a big problem. Just a little ineffecient. I will write unit test to prove that. 
Yes, this seems to be working, I think will use this solution if there is no better way.

Comment: Although this may work, but I suppose it'll make the hash-map totally useless and function like a list. Maybe you should consider using another data-structure for storing and searching your data?

Comment: How about making a wrapper class to hold 3 hash-maps (one per object key)?

Comment: @Hack06 The inefficiency of the lookup depends on the ratio of empty keys you expect. Even if half the objects have empty keys, you'd still have significant gains over just using a linear list. I don't understand your suggestion about creating a wrapper class with 3 maps. Maybe you should write up an answer to demonstrate it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your original question and the comments discussed under it and Robby's answer, I would reformulate your question as follows: How to manage a set of objects having 3 different keys used for equality matching, in an optimal way? So I will be answering to this question, in case someone will blame for not answering to the original one.

My suggestion is to make a wrapper class to hold 3 hash-maps and compare your Student objects with those 3 String keys with its help.

Here's my implementation, with an assumption that your keys are public fields instead of being private as mentioned in your original post.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class StudentX {
    private HashMap<String, Student> map1 = new HashMap();
    private HashMap<String, Student> map2 = new HashMap();
    private HashMap<String, Student> map3 = new HashMap();

    public void addStudent(Student s) {
        map1.put(s.idTypeA, s);
        map2.put(s.idTypeB, s);
        map3.put(s.idTypeC, s);
    }

    public void bulkAddStudents(List<Student> allStudents) {
        for (Student s : allStudents) {
            addStudent(s);
        }
    }

    public Student findStudent(Student s) {
        Student result;
        result = map1.get(s.idTypeA);
        if (result != null) {
            return result;
        }
        result = map2.get(s.idTypeB);
        if (result != null) {
            return result;
        }
        result = map3.get(s.idTypeC);
        if (result != null) {
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and here's some code for testing it, or to understand how I imagined using it:

```
List<Student> students = new LinkedList();

students.add(new Student("spades", "hearts", "diamonds"));
students.add(new Student("hearts", "diamonds", "clubs"));
students.add(new Student("spades", "diamonds", "hearts"));

StudentX group = new StudentX();
group.bulkAddStudents(students);

Student noob = new Student("diamonds", "clubs", "hearts");  //try different values for proper testing
if (group.findStudent(noob) != null) {
    System.out.println("Student found");
} else {
    System.out.println("Student not found");
}
```

Hope this was clear what I meant with a wrapper class to hold 3 hash-maps for optimal searching and comparison.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. This is also a possible solution. Just wonder three duplicate maps will have more entries to store the references of the objects. I will also consider the memory cost, see if this one meet our requirement.

Comment: You're most welcome. Regarding to the memory vs. speed trade-off, there's always a need to better understand the problem and your priorities. I can't provide you a formal proof of impossibility of your original problem to be optimally solved with just overriding the hashCode() function, but it was clear to me that you need a more global approach to the problem. If you need a faster fix then go with Robby's solution, but if you have more time and wish to optimize your code for processing performance, I'm sure my suggestion is worth trying.